# Function pointer in Ruby that doesn't violate access rules

Tags: ruby, function-pointers, pointer-to-member

In C++ I can do this:

```cpp
(condition ? sin : cos)(0.5);
```

or

```cpp
typedef std::deque<int> T;
(T().*(condition ? &T::push_back : &T::push_front))(1);
```

What would be an equivalent of this in Ruby?

I know I can use `send` or `method`, but they allow me to call `private` methods.

```rb
# String#puts and String#print are private
("".method condition ? :puts : :print).call
```

Comment: `if` forces me to repeat arguments twice: `if condition a.f(1) else a.g(1) end`. I want to avoid that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`send` is the way to go in Ruby. If you don't like it because it allows to call private methods, use [`public_send`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-public_send) instead:

```
Math.public_send(condition ? :sin : :cos, 0.5)
```

Comment: Sounds kinda inefficient, though. I timed it and calling method directly is faster than calling it through `send`. In C++ there's no overhead, except for missed optimization opportunity.